# Como planejar autenticar multiplas fontes de acesso Spring API Gateway?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, controle-de-fluxo

Como implantar duas formas de autenticação no componente de software **API Gateway** SpringBoot 3.2.1?

As requições que chegar com a URI:

`/docs/**` deve ser autenticada na fontes de dados em InMemory

`/api/**` devem chamar uma API JWT para validar o usuário

Intenção solução, mas ainda não consegui desenrolar a necessidade

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
http
    .authorizeExchange((authorize) -> authorize
        .pathMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/api/**").access((authentication, context) ->
            // imaginando ir por essas linhas
        )
        .pathMatchers("/docs/**").access((authentication, context) ->
            // imaginando ir por essas linhas
        )
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
    );
    return http.build();
}
```